# VBA code to compare two sheets based on data dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel sheets, One numeric and another text.
Numeric and text sheet has 5 observations and the first column is country. Data dictionary for country is 1='US', 2='Germany',3='India',4='China'.
I am looking for a VBA code that can compare values between two sheets based on data dictionary codes. Also the country column shouldn't have any data other than what is available in data dictionary. In this example, there is also an option 5 that is not available in dictionary and this needs to be highlighted as error.

```
Sheet1: Numeric    Sheet2: Text
Country            Country
1                  US
1                  US
2                  Germany
3                  India
4                  China
5                  China
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: This could be done purely using in-cell Excel formulas and conditional formatting rather than VBA. Suggest you look at creating a separate sheet containing the data dictionary and use VLOOKUP.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. What I gave is an example. In real, I have 200 columns and 50k observations. Applying conditional formatting and using vlookup is tedious considering the amount of data. I would like to automate the data quality check process by comparing Numeric and Text sheets, also ensuring that the values recorded for a variable is as per data dictionary. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the comment maintain two consecutive columns in any sheet, first one with the country code and other one with the corresponding country name. then use can use `vlookup()` function to get the the country name... [for ref click here](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/how-to-use-excels-vlookup-function/1/)

[image: Implementation- example]